# Using two file uploads in same form in primefaces

Tags: primefaces

I am using Primefaces 3.2. I am using two file upload handlers in the same form. When I am uploading the file in the first, the file name is reflected in both of the upload handlers.

Comment: What is your actual question here?

Comment: how about using single file upload handler with multiple file upload option ?

Comment: my requirement is two upload handlers.So i am using two file upload handlers in same form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple advanced file uploaders in the same form is not supported. This is stated in primefaces users guide, page 181. you can try using basic file upload.

Comment: What if I want to use two file uploaders in the same form? In my case I will need two file uploaders in the same form just to have the assurance that the two files are uploaded using the right loader. Another reason, is that the two files the user has to upload are not all required.

Comment: at the time of this answer it was not possible. check in the user guide of the current version of primefaces. you'll probably have to use 2 forms and make them work together with code.

Comment: Thanks @Damian, I guess that is tedious!